# django, contenttype and m2m generic relations

Tags: python, django, m2m, django-contenttypes

I have the following models:

1. Application

   1. Contact Form
   2. Game
   3. Landing Page
2. Client

After I add a new Client, I want to add new applications under client. For this, I added a m2m  field under Clients to Applications like this:

```
applications = models.ManyToManyField(Application, verbose_name=u'Applications')
```

Since an application can be anything, I found out that I needed to use contenttype framework. So I placed the following under Application model:

```
applicationContentType = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
applicationId = models.PositiveIntegerField()
application = generic.GenericForeignKey('applicationContentType', 'applicationId')
```

This way I can add new applications by selecting content type (content form in this case) and typing existing Contact Form's id. And I can see it in Client's m2m field on admin page.

However when I do the following, I can't see the application I just added to the Client:

```
In [2]: t = Client.objects.get()
In [3]: t.applications.all()
Out[3]: []
```

And having to remember the newly added Contact Form's id is not very nice. Is there an elegant solution of this? Or should I change my point of view to the problem and do it in a different way?

Comment: Hello, as far as I can see this "t = Client.objects.get()" wont produce any output because theres no parameter to the objects.get(). Your Application model has a generic foreign key, which enables it to be attached to any other models you create (ie. contact form, game, landing page). Could be a little more precise which goal you want to achieve?

Comment: It works because I already added an object with that model. get() works as if you wrote get(pk=1)

Comment: I thought Application model class as a container to other applications (Contact Form etc) so that I could add them 1 by 1 via m2m relationship to Client model class.

Comment: t.applications.all() should retrieve all m2m related objects, if there are any attached. I dont see why this shouldnt work except there are no applications attached to the client with pk=1.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I know this is a very old question, but thought someone might benifit this*

What you are describing would work perfectly if the each of the application models (or [their `abstract` parent](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)) would have a m2m key to the client. I would not recommend using generic foreign keys unless it's absolutely inevitable (trust me, you'll thank me later).

For instance, take an application model:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...

    client = models.ManyToManyField('clients.Client',
                                    related_name="related_%(class)s")
```

Using this approach you will have the reverse fields available to the client via the `related_games`, `related_contactforms` and `related_landingpages` respectively.